# insufficient privilieges error

Tags: sql, oracle

I've been executing various pl/sql procedures on a certain schema and they all execute fine. But while executing a one particular procedure i get the error as

```
SQL> execute call_para_cursor
BEGIN call_para_cursor; END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
ORA-06512: at "SYSTEM.CALL_PARA_CURSOR", line 4
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Though i'm executing the procedure on the same schema, its asking me for more privileges.
How do i get around this situation?

```
create or replace procedure call_para_cursor as

BEGIN
 execute immediate ' create or replace procedure para_cursor_test as
cursor c_p_det(tar_val number) is select name, salary from fees where salary    < tar_val;
nname varchar2(30);
ssalary number(5);
BEGIN
Open c_p_det(1000);
LOOP
FETCH c_p_det into nname, ssalary;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(NNAME || SSALARY);
EXIT WHEN C_P_DET%NOTFOUND;
END LOOP;
CLOSE C_P_DET;
END';

dbms_output.put_line('done processing !!');
END;
```

Comment: Google `grant` for oracle

Comment: Look at line 4 of SYSTEM.CALL_PARA_CURSOR.

Comment: @JonHeller :i created a new schema and tried the same... but no go... it runs all the  procedures butnot the ones with dynamic code ie execute immediate... this time it gives an error "procedure not found".. i think there is a catch i running dynamic procedures... any idea? when i delete the dynamic code from the same procedure, it runs just fine an produces the required output... so i think there is a catch...!!

Comment: @codepoetly You might want to try defining the procedure as `authid current_user as ...`.  Then it will run with the privileges of the user currently executing the code, not the one owning the code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is a combination of a few things:

1. The procedure is run as definer's rights, by default.  Only privileges granted directly to the procedure owner will be used when the procedure is executed.  Privileges granted through roles are ignored.
2. The procedure is owned by SYSTEM, which does not have the `EXECUTE PROCEDURE` directly granted to it by default.
3. But before you run `grant execute procedure to system;` - you almost certainly do not want to use SYSTEM for any custom code.

Comment: logged in sysdba and tried the above steps but no go.... same output... "insufficient privileges"

Comment: @codepoetly You need to completely re-design what you're doing.  Your application should not involve either SYSTEM or SYS.

Comment: system is just the name of the schema im working in.. so also I never had problems executing any other procedures in the same schema which also involved dynamic plsql..

Comment: @codepoetly You're not supposed to do anything in SYSTEM.  There's probably a way to make this work.  But whenever someone sees this program the first thing they're going to tell you is to use a different schema, so you might as well change it now.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with functions and procedures, you can grant users the ability to EXECUTE these functions and procedures.

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON object TO user;
```

**object** :The name of the database object that you are granting privileges for.

**user**: The name of the user that will be granted the EXECUTE privileges.

Comment: did that prior to asking here... did it again... grant succeeded... but on execute the output is still 'insufficient privileges'.... also when i search for the object in all_objects or any other table it does not return any results.

Comment: select * from all_objects where object_name = 'call_para_cursor';    ..... no rows selected. tried all the tables as well (user and all)(procedures and objects).... but no rows selected

Comment: connect with sysdba and try grant all privileges to userName;